# Oracle find column name and values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table in an Oracle database:

```
Table - TEST_TABLE1

FIELD_1    FIELD_2    FIELD_3   FIELD_4  FIELD_5
-------------------------------------------------
 NA         123        NA         NA      NA
```

I have to check the column name from last column to first column who is not having value 'NA'
i.e in this case my output would be

```
FIELD_2
-------
123
```

Appreciate for any help.

Comment: In SQL a table has _columns_, not _fields_...

Comment: This makes no sense. You want to return the **column** FIELD_2? What if in another row FIELD_5 is already an actual value, not NA? Surely you don't think you can write a query that returns FIELD_2 **only** and also FIELD_5 **only** (in the same output). Please think again about the problem, come up with a better statement, and edit your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `decode`. '
As said by @mathguy,the column heading ( `FIELD_2` ) can't be captured or displayed this way.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5e588/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (FIELD_1 varchar2(4), FIELD_2 varchar2(4), FIELD_3 varchar2(4), FIELD_4 varchar2(4), FIELD_5 varchar2(4))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 (FIELD_1, FIELD_2, FIELD_3, FIELD_4, FIELD_5)
         VALUES ('NA', '123', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA')
    INTO Table1 (FIELD_1, FIELD_2, FIELD_3, FIELD_4, FIELD_5)
         VALUES ('NA', '123', 'NA', '345', 'NA')     
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
        select decode(FIELD_5, 'NA' ,
               decode(FIELD_4, 'NA',
               decode(FIELD_3, 'NA',
               decode(FIELD_2, 'NA',
               decode(FIELD_1, 'NA',
                      NULL,
                      FIELD_1),
                      FIELD_2),
                      FIELD_3)
                      ,FIELD_4)
                      ,FIELD_5) as val FROM Table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5e588/1/0)**:

```
| VAL |
|-----|
| 123 |
| 345 |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I would like to know whether can we display the column name as well? like                                                                                                
'COLUMN_NAME | VAL |'
'----------------------------------'
'FIELD_2              | 123 |'
'FIELD_3              | 345 |'

Comment: @AmitJadhav : You may use an  `UNPIVOT` or multiple `UNION ALL` s. It would be a different solution to that problem and is not similar to the desired o/p expected by this question. You may google how to use `UNPIVOT` or  ask that as a separate question

Answer (score 1):

Typically 'NA' (i.e. not available) expressions in databases are denoted as `NULL`.

You may consider to update your table like

```
update TEST_TABLE1 set 
FIELD_1 = NULL
WHERE FIELD_1 = 'NA';
```

Anyway, for your selection I would propose this one:

```
select COALESCE(NULLIF(FIELD_1, 'NA'), NULLIF(FIELD_2, 'NA'), NULLIF(FIELD_3, 'NA'), NULLIF(FIELD_4, 'NA'), NULLIF(FIELD_5, 'NA'))
from TEST_TABLE1;
```

If you update your table with `NULL` then the query would be shorter as

```
select COALESCE(FIELD_1, FIELD_2, FIELD_3, FIELD_4, FIELD_5)
from TEST_TABLE1;
```

Comment: I couldn't have the correct results when i try http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e8e68/1. Moreover, you need to emphasize the types of any columns ( including FIELD_2 ) mustn't be numeric so that NULLIF(FIELD_2, 'NA') works.